# check which drop down was changed

Tags: jquery

i have a form where i want to know which drop down list was modified. how can i accomplish this using jquery? i know for textbox controls you can do some thing like

```
$("input[type='text']").change(function() {
        // do something here
    });
```

but i need to do something similar for drop down list controls.

Comment: By "dropdown" do you mean a `select` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(function(e){
        console.log($(e.currentTarget));
    });
});
```

The `currentTarget` attribute of the event object will give you access to the specific element that triggered the event.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select").change(function() {
    // do something here
});
```

Comment: +1 That's the answer I'd have given, but I wasn't sure the O/P meant a select.

Comment: Doing a lot of ASP.NET; whenever I hear dropdown I just assume select

Comment: Got ya. I have never touched ASP of any flavor, so the term was somewhat foreign to me. :)